# How to invoke a conventional REST-RPC call with the Atmosphere framework?

Tags: rest, websocket, jersey, atmosphere

How do I send POST/PUT/DELETE calls to a rest source using Atmosphere 1.1.0+ in a conventional RPC manner? (You are guessing right, I want to employ pub/sub and RPC style in my project)

serverside: register a @Path (e.g. /member), mark with @POST/@PUT/@DELETE, process the method body and `return` the value. Seems straight forward. Even with JSON en-/decoding.

clientside: How would you kick a POST request with the wasync library? All atmosphere examples use "GET" and recommended to use GET only. Why is that?

```
RequestBuilder request = client.newRequestBuilder().method(Request.METHOD.GET).uri("/member")
```

Can one expect this synchronous server response when invoking the fire method? e.g.

```
Future future = socket.fire(myMemberObject)
```

Thank you for hints and comments on this approach (also thoights on pairing RPC and PubSub are welcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wAsync is using POST once the connection is established. wAsync is asynchronous by nature so you need to use Latch if you want to make it blocking, or use AsyncHttpClient with Future.

Comment: Thanks. I checked your example. Makes sense. Still, some implementations are not clear to me. If wAsync invokes (open socket, invoke fire method) a REST-resource method, how does the Atmosphere-Jersey serverside return an immediate (but asynchronous) response? It uses the return statment, doesn't? Is the websocket connection terminated after this response? If not, why not? If yes, how can you still communicate with the wAsync client? Leading me to the next question: how do you send messages from the server to previously subscribed clients (Atmosphere-REST resources with @Subscribed)?

Comment: I did understand your chat example where clients send a message to a @Subscribe-annotated REST-resource, and this message is immediatly returned to all other clients that previously subscribed. Well, but how does the server send one of these messages to the subscribed users? How do I repeatedly send messages to these subscribers? What did I miss in this PubSub implementation of Atmosphere-Jersey? I appreciate your comments and recommendations on how to use Atmosphere and wAsync in a (async) REST style.

Comment: last question: firing a message on a socket to a Atmosphere REST-resource using wASync, what can I expect in the return object Future? nothing, since it's async, as you mentioned in your answer? sorry, also unclear to me.

Comment: I need to write a blog entry, which address and illustrate my questions with additional samples. i.e. best practices with wasync and atmosphere.